# How to get to button attr in other td in the same row by checkbox if checked?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Table looks like this:

```
<table class="table3">
                <tbody><tr>
                    <td>
                        <input id="checkall" type="checkbox">
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        Autor
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        Komentarz
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        Data dodania
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        Post
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        Status
                    </td>
                </tr>
                                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="comment[]" value="1">
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        cipka<br>cipuszka@o2.pl                 </td>
                    <td>
                        sadasdsad                   </td>
                    <td>
                        2017-06-03                  </td>
                    <td>
                        Przykładowy Tytuł Strony                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <button id="1" class="yellow-button btn">Odpublicznij</button><button id="1" class="red-button btn">Usuń</button>                   </td>
                </tr>
                                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="comment[]" value="5">
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        Cipenia<br>Cifuszka@o2.pl                   </td>
                    <td>
                        aoskdopaskdop



                    </td>
                    <td>
                        2017-06-04                  </td>
                    <td>
                        Przykładowy Tytuł Strony                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <button id="5" class="yellow-button btn">Odpublicznij</button><button id="5" class="red-button btn">Usuń</button>                   </td>
                </tr>
                                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="comment[]" value="11">
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        54345345<br>                    </td>
                    <td>
                                            </td>
                    <td>
                        0000-00-00                  </td>
                    <td>
                        Burde lubie kielbaske se zjesc!                 </td>
                    <td>
                        <button id="11" class="yellow-button btn">Odpublicznij</button><button id="11" class="red-button btn">Usuń</button>                 </td>
                </tr>
                                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="comment[]" value="25">
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        234324234<br>                   </td>
                    <td>
                                            </td>
                    <td>
                        0000-00-00                  </td>
                    <td>
                        Burde lubie kielbaske se zjesc!                 </td>
                    <td>
                        <button id="25" class="yellow-button btn">Odpublicznij</button><button id="25" class="red-button btn">Usuń</button>                 </td>
                </tr>
                            </tbody></table>
```

I have many checkboxes.

We have some checkboxes. How to get to button's attribute in the same row as checked checkbox and change this button's class?

I have this to get all checked checkboxes `$("input[type=checkbox]:checked")`

But how to change now all button's classes in these rows where checkbox is checked?

I tried `$("input[type=checkbox]:checked").closest('button').attr('class', 'new_class');` but it doesn't work.

`$("input[type=checkbox]:checked").parent().closest('button').attr('class', 'new_class');` doesn't work too.

Comment: maybe try `$("input:checked button").addClass("nameOfNewClass");` ? Hope this helps you out!

Comment: didn't work @N.Ivanov

Comment: what about if you get the given `<tr>` and then use [jQuery Docs](https://api.jquery.com/find/) this to find your button?

Comment: Check my update answer, the second code snippet. I think this will be really helpful to you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`closest` traverses **up** the DOM tree until it hits the given selector.
`find` traverses **down**

So you should use `closest` to get table row, and then use `find` to go back down the ancestry chain and get the button(s).

```
$('input[type=checkbox]').on('change',function(){
  var $checkbox = $( this );
  $checkbox.closest( 'tr' )
    .find('button')
    .toggleClass('blue',$checkbox.is(':checked'));
}).trigger('change');
```

I've had a play and made a codepen for you: https://codepen.io/jamespoel/pen/awGdqK

Comment: If closets traversers up the DOM why it didn't find button in other tr?
Tr that is above tr from where which we start?
for example.

`<tr>
<td>
<checkbox>
</td>
<td>
<button><--------------found button traversing up the DOM
</td>----no button
</tr>----no button
<tr>----no button
<td>--- no button
<checkbox> <--------- we start here, checking this
</td>
<td>
<button>
</td>
</tr>`'

Comment: `closest` checks each parent element until the given selector is matched. The button is not a parent of the checkbox. The initial parent of the checkbox is the **td**, the parent of the **td** is the **tr**. Therefore `checkbox.closest('tr')` returns the table row that contains the checkbox. `checkbox.closest('tr').find('button')` returns all child button elements of the table row. I think you misunderstand how the dom is constructed and parent/child relationships within it. There's loads of info about this online. :-)

Answer (score 1):

This is a simple logic. Here is what you need to do. Add a class when the checkbox is checked and remove that class when it is unchecked. You can achieve this by detecting the closest `<tr>` of the checkbox that has been clicked and then when you get this `<tr>` simply find the `<button>` tag. This will be a array of elements since you have two `<button>` inside a `<tr>`. Here you need to use JQuery `each()` function and add or remove class accordingly. Here is the working code that will surely help you.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

  $("input[type=checkbox]").click(function(){
      var trButtons = $(this).closest('tr').find('button');
      if($(this).prop('checked')){
         $(trButtons).each(function(){
            $(this).addClass('selectedButton');
         });
      }else{
         $(trButtons).each(function(){
            $(this).removeClass('selectedButton');
         });
      }
     
  });

});
```

```css
.selectedButton{
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table3">
                <tbody><tr>
                    <td>
                        <input id="checkall" type="checkbox">
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        Autor
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        Komentarz
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        Data dodania
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        Post
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        Status
                    </td>
                </tr>
                                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="comment[]" value="1">
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        cipka<br>cipuszka@o2.pl                 </td>
                    <td>
                        sadasdsad                   </td>
                    <td>
                        2017-06-03                  </td>
                    <td>
                        Przykładowy Tytuł Strony                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <button id="1" class="yellow-button btn">Odpublicznij</button><button id="1" class="red-button btn">Usuń</button>                   </td>
                </tr>
                                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="comment[]" value="5">
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        Cipenia<br>Cifuszka@o2.pl                   </td>
                    <td>
                        aoskdopaskdop



                    </td>
                    <td>
                        2017-06-04                  </td>
                    <td>
                        Przykładowy Tytuł Strony                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <button id="5" class="yellow-button btn">Odpublicznij</button><button id="5" class="red-button btn">Usuń</button>                   </td>
                </tr>
                                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="comment[]" value="11">
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        54345345<br>                    </td>
                    <td>
                                            </td>
                    <td>
                        0000-00-00                  </td>
                    <td>
                        Burde lubie kielbaske se zjesc!                 </td>
                    <td>
                        <button id="11" class="yellow-button btn">Odpublicznij</button><button id="11" class="red-button btn">Usuń</button>                 </td>
                </tr>
                                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="comment[]" value="25">
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        234324234<br>                   </td>
                    <td>
                                            </td>
                    <td>
                        0000-00-00                  </td>
                    <td>
                        Burde lubie kielbaske se zjesc!                 </td>
                    <td>
                        <button id="25" class="yellow-button btn">Odpublicznij</button><button id="25" class="red-button btn">Usuń</button>                 </td>
                </tr>
                            </tbody></table>
```

Use this code if you want that master checkbox on the table header to work

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#checkall').click(function(){
    var isChecked = $(this).prop('checked');
    var allTr = $('tbody').find('tr').not(':first');
    $(allTr).each(function(){
         var cbInsideTr = $(this).find('input[type="checkbox"]');
         $(cbInsideTr).prop('checked',!isChecked);
         $(cbInsideTr).trigger( "click" );
     });
  });
  $("input[type=checkbox]").click(function(){
      var trButtons = $(this).closest('tr').find('button');
      if($(this).prop('checked')){
         $(trButtons).each(function(){
            $(this).addClass('selectedButton');
         });
      }else{
         $(trButtons).each(function(){
            $(this).removeClass('selectedButton');
         });
      }
  });

});
```

```css
.selectedButton{
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table3">
                <tbody><tr>
                    <td>
                        <input id="checkall" type="checkbox">
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        Autor
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        Komentarz
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        Data dodania
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        Post
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        Status
                    </td>
                </tr>
                                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="comment[]" value="1">
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        cipka<br>cipuszka@o2.pl                 </td>
                    <td>
                        sadasdsad                   </td>
                    <td>
                        2017-06-03                  </td>
                    <td>
                        Przykładowy Tytuł Strony                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <button id="1" class="yellow-button btn">Odpublicznij</button><button id="1" class="red-button btn">Usuń</button>                   </td>
                </tr>
                                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="comment[]" value="5">
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        Cipenia<br>Cifuszka@o2.pl                   </td>
                    <td>
                        aoskdopaskdop



                    </td>
                    <td>
                        2017-06-04                  </td>
                    <td>
                        Przykładowy Tytuł Strony                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <button id="5" class="yellow-button btn">Odpublicznij</button><button id="5" class="red-button btn">Usuń</button>                   </td>
                </tr>
                                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="comment[]" value="11">
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        54345345<br>                    </td>
                    <td>
                                            </td>
                    <td>
                        0000-00-00                  </td>
                    <td>
                        Burde lubie kielbaske se zjesc!                 </td>
                    <td>
                        <button id="11" class="yellow-button btn">Odpublicznij</button><button id="11" class="red-button btn">Usuń</button>                 </td>
                </tr>
                                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="comment[]" value="25">
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        234324234<br>                   </td>
                    <td>
                                            </td>
                    <td>
                        0000-00-00                  </td>
                    <td>
                        Burde lubie kielbaske se zjesc!                 </td>
                    <td>
                        <button id="25" class="yellow-button btn">Odpublicznij</button><button id="25" class="red-button btn">Usuń</button>                 </td>
                </tr>
                            </tbody></table>
```

Comment: Nice answer. However ln 5-13 can simply be:
`trButtons.toggleClass( 'selectedButton',  $(this).prop('checked') );`. `trButtons` is already a jQuery element so doesn't need to be wrapped in `$(...)` either :-) Toggle Class: http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/

Comment: I am working on the main checkbox now and update my answer so that when the top checkbox in the table head is selected all is selected and vice versa. I would expect at least a up vote for the current answer. I will get value for my time.

Comment: Check my update answer, the second code snippet. I think this will be really helpful to you.

Answer (score 0):

you can get clicked row's button like this

```
$("input:checkbox").click(function(){
    console.log($(this).closest("tr").find(".btn").attr("id"));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

simply write like this

$("input[type=checkbox]:checked").closest('tr').find('button').attr('class', 'new_class');